# Bash substring from position not printing

Tags: linux, string, bash, scripting

I am using the following format `#{string:start:length}` to extract the file name from wget's `.listing` file, line by line.

The format for the file is something I think we are all familiar with:

```
04-30-13  01:41AM              7033614 some_archive.zip
04-29-13  08:13PM       <DIR>          DIRECTORY NAME 1
04-29-13  05:41PM       <DIR>          DIRECTORY NAME 2
```

All file names start at pos:40, so setting `:start` to 39, with no `:length` should (and does) return the file name for each line:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat .listing | while read line; do
    file="${line:40}"
    echo $file
done
```

Correctly returns:

```
some_archive.zip
DIRECTORY NAME 1
DIRECTORY NAME 2
```

However, if I get any more creative, it breaks:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat .listing | while read line; do
    file="${line:40}"
    dir=$(echo $line | egrep -o '<DIR>' | head -n1)
    if [ $dir ]; then
        echo "the file $file is a $dir"
    fi
done
```

Returns:

```
$ ./test.sh
 is a <DIR>ECTORY NAME 1
 is a <DIR>ECTORY NAME 2
```

What gives?  I lose "the file " and the rest of the test looks like it prints on top of "the file DIRECTORY NAME 1" from pos:0.

It's weird, what's it on account of?

Comment: It looks like your input file has DOS line endings. The `\r` is causing everything following `$file` to be printed at the beginning of the line, overwriting what precedes it.

Comment: What @chepner said, use the tool `dos2unix` on your .listing file to fix it

Comment: The thing is.  This is a Unix box and the .listing file was created with wget, and edited with vi only.  Where did the dos chars come from?

Comment: "created with wget". I would assume the fetched file had DOS line endings.

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't consider that.  I guess I thought the `.listing` file was created by, yes, pulling the index, but then parsed in some way to make `.listing`.

Although, now that you mention it, I do remember somewhere that FTP servers will return a 'LISTING', and this must be that raw data.  Neat.  Again with the learning things.

Comment: @GerhardBurger - I do not have the luxury of installing that on this machine.

Comment: the `tr -d '\015'` command does the same, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as I am learning more and more with linux as I progress, is non-printing control characters.

Adding a pipe to `egrep` for only printing characters solved the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat .listing | while read line; do
    file=$(echo ${line:39} | egrep -o '[[:print:]]+' | head -n1)
    dir=$(echo $line | egrep -o '<DIR>' | head -n1)
    if [ $dir ]; then
        echo "the file $file is a $dir"
    fi
done
```

Correctly returns:

```
$ ./test.sh
the file DIRECTORY NAME 1 is a <DIR>
the file DIRECTORY NAME 2 is a <DIR>
```

Wish there were a better way to visualize these control characters, but what the above does is basically take the string segment, pull out the first string of printable characters, and assign it to the variable.

I assume there is a control character at the end of the line that returns the cursor to the beginning of the line.  Causing the rest of the `echo` to be printed there, overwriting the previous characters.'

Odd.

Comment: you always can: `od -bc file` or `cat -v file` to show control characters... Also, the `less` command has a couple of environment variables for how to show nonprintable characters...

Comment: THANK YOU for those commands.  That's going to be a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `\r` control characters from the whole file by using the `tr` command on the first line of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat .listing | tr -d '\015' | while read line; do
    file="${line:39}"
    dir=$(echo $line | egrep -o '<DIR>' | head -n1)
    if [ $dir ]; then
        echo "the file $file is a $dir"
    fi
done
```